# Exibir alerta ao Carregar a página

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5, alert

Estou usando asp.net-mvc e até onde sei o evento OnLoad funcionaria se colocasse em body, que fica em ~Layout, mas preciso que este alerta fosse exibido em uma página única, pois se eu colocar em body será executado toda vez... como posso fazer?

codigo da View:

```
@model Tribus.Models.Pagamento

@{
    var Id = Session["PacoteID"];
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //window.onload = window.alert("entrou aqui");

        window.onload = function () {
            var id = $(this).attr(Id);//id do item

            window.alert(id);
            var url = '@Url.Action("RetornoRegistrar", "Pagamento")';
            $.post(url, { id: id },
            function (data) {
                window.alert("Registrado com Sucesso\nLogo seu produto será liberado.")
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Podes explicar melhor _"fosse exibido em uma página única"_? queres dizer numa página especifica ou só uma vez para cada utilizador?

Comment: Isso, seria uma página que o usuário iria passar, durante um processo e quando ele entrar nesta tela, o alerta é disparado pra ele. eu só queria saber como posso chamar a função ao carregar esta página.

Comment: @Sergio coloquei o código da página

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o RenderSection do Razor...

Ele serve pra criar uma seção no Layout para você especificar nas Views que implementam onde o código será acoplado quando renderizado. Você pode usar para fins de scripts ou css.

Ele é composto por dois parâmetros principais. O primeiro é o nome e o segundo se é obrigatório.

**@RenderSection("nomeSection", required: false)**

**OBS: Observe que o segundo parametro está como "false", mas coloque como true, caso queira definir a declaração da section obrigatória para cada View que implementar o layout.**

Na sua situação você terá que fazer da seguinte forma:

No _Layout.cshtml acrescente o RenderSection ao final do body (já que se trata de um script e o recomendável é ficar ao final do body)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

Você implementará a Section na seguinte maneira:

**@section nomeSection{ "codigo que você vai implementar" }**

No seu código:

```
@model Tribus.Models.Pagamento

@{
    var Id = Session["PacoteID"];
}

@section scripts{

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //window.onload = window.alert("entrou aqui");

        window.onload = function () {
            var id = $(this).attr(Id);//id do item

            window.alert(id);
            var url = '@Url.Action("RetornoRegistrar", "Pagamento")';
            $.post(url, { id: id },
            function (data) {
                window.alert("Registrado com Sucesso\nLogo seu produto será liberado.")
            });
        });
    });
</script>

}
```

Daí remova o comentário do //window.onload = window.alert("entrou aqui"); e verifique se funciona tudo corretamente.